# OpenGL: How to make light stationary when moving the camera around?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I'm trying to render a simple (10x3x10 in size) room using OpenGL and GLUT, written in C.

I'd like to create a simple statinary spotlight, while i can move around in the room.

(The ultimate goal is to make a spotlight coming from a lamp at the ceiling)

**The problem is the light changes when i move the camera around.**

I'm calling the following function from `main()`:

```
void init() {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    loadTexture(); // loading some textures using SOIL
    loadModels(); // loading some OBJ models

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glClearDepth(1);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

The function i pass to `glutDisplayFunc()`:

```
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    initLight();

    gluLookAt(x, 1.5f, z, x + vX, 1.5f, z + vZ, 0.0f, 1.5f, 0.0f);

    // ...
    // drawing the ground, ceiling and the walls
    // no matrix transformations here, just simple glVertex () calls
    // ...

    glPushMatrix();

    // drawing a table
    glTranslatef(5, 0.842843, 5);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
    draw_model(&modelTable);

    // drawing some chairs
    glTranslatef(0, -0.312053, chair1Position);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
    draw_model(&modelChair1);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, chair2Position);
    draw_model(&modelChair2);

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

And the `initLight()` function:

```
void initLight() {

    // i would like the light to originate from an upper corner
    // directed to the opposing lower corner (across the room basically)

    GLfloat lightPosition[] = { 10, 3, 0, 1 };
    GLfloat lightDirection[] = { 0, 0, 10, 0 };
    GLfloat ambientLight[] = { 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1 };
    GLfloat diffuseLight[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 180);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 64);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightDirection);
}
```

I was told this problem could be solved by the proper positioning of the `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` calls.

Wherever i put them, the light either keeps changing when i'm moving the camera or i got no light at all. I just cannot figure it out.

What would be a proper solution here?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
I've moved the `initLight()` call to after the `gluLookAt()` call as @derhass suggested below.
The light is still changing when i'm moving around.

There are two screenshots below.

On the first one the light is not even visible. When i turn slightly to the right, it appears.
[image]
[image]

**EDIT2**:

The full (stripped down) source code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>
#include <math.h>

GLfloat lightPosition[] = { 10, 3, 0, 1 };
GLfloat lightDirection[] = { 0, 0, 10, 0 };
GLfloat diffuseLight[] = { 0, 1, 0, 1 };
GLfloat ambientLight[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1 };

float x = 1.0f, z = 5.0f;
float vX = 1.0f, vZ = 0.0f;
float angle = 1.5f;

int windowWidth = 1024;
int windowHeight = 768;

char* textureFiles[13] = { "floortexture.png", "tabletexture.png",
        "chairtexture.png", "orange.png", "helptexture.png",
        "fridgetexture.png", "oven.png", "yellow.png", "dishwasher.png",
        "metallic.png", "cabinet.png", "wood.png", "cabinet2.png" };
GLuint texture[13];

void loadTexture() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        texture[i] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(textureFiles[i], SOIL_LOAD_RGBA,
                SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, 0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    }
}

void init() {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    loadTexture();

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glClearDepth(1);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

void processSpecialKeys(int key, int xx, int yy) {

    float moveFraction = 0.2f;
    float angleFraction = 0.1f;

    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        angle -= angleFraction;
        vX = sin(angle);
        vZ = -cos(angle);
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        angle += angleFraction;
        vX = sin(angle);
        vZ = -cos(angle);
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        x += vX * moveFraction;
        z += vZ * moveFraction;
        if (x < 1) {
            x = 1;
        }
        if (z < 1) {
            z = 1;
        }
        if (x > 9) {
            x = 9;
        }
        if (z > 9) {
            z = 9;
        }
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        x -= vX * moveFraction;
        z -= vZ * moveFraction;
        if (x < 1) {
            x = 1;
        }
        if (z < 1) {
            z = 1;
        }
        if (x > 9) {
            x = 9;
        }
        if (z > 9) {
            z = 9;
        }
        break;
    }
}

void initLight() {
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 180);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 128);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightDirection);
}

void renderWalls() {
    // floor
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 8);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(8, 8);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(8, 0);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glEnd();

    // walls
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[3]);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    // first wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glEnd();

    // second wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 3.0f, 10.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

    glEnd();

    // third wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 3.0f, 10.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 10.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

    glEnd();

    // fourth wall
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 10.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

    glEnd();

    // ceiling
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[7]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, 3.0f, 10.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 10.0f);

    glEnd();
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(x, 1.5f, z, x + vX, 1.5f, z + vZ, 0.0f, 1.5f, 0.0f);
    initLight();

    renderWalls();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void changeWindowSize(int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0) {
        height = 1;
    }

    float ratio = 1.0 * width / height;

    windowWidth = width;
    windowHeight = height;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gluPerspective(45.0f, ratio, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glutCreateWindow("Kitchen");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(changeWindowSize);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about having the camera and the light in the same reference system, so you'd get the desired effect?

Comment: @LuisColorado Thanks for your reply. How could i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your light *is* stationary - but to the camera.

Fixed-function OpenGL does all the lighting calculations in eye space. At the moment you specify the `GL_POSITION` of a light, it is transformed according to the *current `modelView` matrix* at the time of the call, to get the eye space position. Since `modelView` is set to identity, it will always set the light to the given eye-space location - no  matter where you later place the camera.

To fix this, just move `initLight()` after the `gluLookAt`.

However. You should not be doing this at all. You are using *deprecated* OpenGL features which you shouldn't use *since a decade* now. In modern GL, that functionality is completely removed. So if you are learning OpenGL in 2016, do yourself a favour and forget about that old cruft, and just learn shaders directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Moving the `initLight()` after the `gluLookAt()` call does not work unfortunately. See my edited question for screenshots. This is an assignment and i have to use these deprecated features. If you have any other ideas why the light still changes when moving around, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it is not clear what we actually see there. How is the "room" modelled? How are the normals set? The lighting is not independent of the viewing position - the specular component is always veiw-dependent. With gouraud shading and low enough tesselation on the faces, the result might even be _correct_. What I don't know is where that irregular dithering comes from. What kind of GL implementation is this?

Comment: I've added a pastebin link to the source code at the end of the question. Stripped it down to the bare minimum for the problem to be reproducible. Please take a look if you have the time. Thank you. I'm using the default OpenGL implementation on my Debian machine.

Comment: Don't link to external code. Put the relevant part directly into the question. However, your normals are completely broken in that link. You will never get proper lighting without supplying the proper normals.

Comment: Oh, those `glNormal` calls weren't supposed to be there in the `renderWalls()` function. Edited the question with the proper source code. Is it still a problem with the normals? If so, please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, there is a huge problem with the normals - you don't supply any. Due to OpenGL's state machine model, you will have a constant normal for all of these vertices, which cannot possibly work. I don't know why you think you can get away without normals. Maybe you think `glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL)` will help you, but that is not the case. That function only releats to GL's evaluator functionality, a feature that is even more obscure than the deprecated GL you are using, and totally irrelevant for the code you pasted.